# Cascading routers and connecting subnetworks

Tags: wireless-router, home-networking

I have wireless routers in different floors and I didn´t find any tutorial howto connect both subnetworks.
Main router (or switch or modem or whatever it is) is not accessible for me.

Main router: IPs range 10.0.1.*

Wireless router A:

- Wan: 10.0.1.18
- LAN: 192.168.1.1

Wireless router B:

- Wan: 10.0.1.19
- LAN: 192.168.2.1

Projector IP: 192.168.1.10

Media server IP: 192.168.2.200

I need to know how to make Projector connect to Media server (this is just an example, I really need to make full connection between networks for printers, accesing media server from other laptops, etc.)

[image: Network design PICTURE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is create a route between the two routers. Basically, that means you will tell router A "You can contact network `192.168.2.0/24` by asking `10.0.1.19`" and reciprocically.

Here is what you need to do:

- On router A:

  - Access its admin page
  - Find the "Static routes" page or something like that
  - Add a route for network `192.168.2.0/24` (or IP `192.168.2.0`, mask `255.255.255.0` - these define the wLAN served by router B) witn gateway `10.0.1.19` (external IP of router B)
  - Don't forget to save & apply the new settings
- On router B:

  - Access its admin page
  - Find the "Static routes" page or something like that
  - Add a route for network `192.168.1.0/24` (or IP `192.168.1.0`, mask `255.255.255.0` - these define the wLAN served by router A) witn gateway `10.0.1.18` (external IP of router A)
  - Don't forget to save & apply the new settings

The admin pages of (w)LAN routers is device-specific, so I can't help you further than that.

Comment: Thanks Nathan ... I will try this when arriving at home...

Comment: Thanks, it was solved... I needed  to make one more routing because 10.0.5.18 and 19 were not connecting, so routes suggested were not working..
I discovered that 10.0.5.* network gateway was 10.0.0.1 so I routed 10.0.5.0/24 to 10.0.0.1 and all worked properly...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted so other people will know where to look.